# An example of a measure and of a set s.t. its measure cannot be approximated by measures of its open subsets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, outer-measure

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a Hausdorff topological space and let $\mu$ be a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$. The measure $\mu$ is (usually) defined to be outer regular if measure of any set $B \in \mathcal{B}$ can be approximated by the measures of the open supersets of $B$, i.e. 
$$ \mu(B) = \inf \{\mu(U): B \subseteq U \in \tau \}.$$

There is a corresponding (dual) definition for inner regularity, where openness is replaced by closedness (and sometimes compactness) and infimum by supremum.

Question: if I require measurable sets to be approximable by measures of its open **sub**sets, i.e. if I want the measures of measurable (e.g. Borel) sets to be a supremum of measures of its open subsets, do I get some kind of trivial notion?

Under the definitions above, let's call a measure $\nu$ (inner) **shregular** if for any nonempty measurable set $G \subseteq X$ we have:
$$\nu(G) = \sup\{\nu(V): V \subseteq G \: \& \: V \in \tau\}.$$

Two questions: is the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ shregular?

Are there examples of non-trivial spaces and measures that are not shregular? Or perhaps there is some silly reason I do not notice for which none 'reasonable' measure is shregular?

If this helps, I would ask a similar question for (outer) shregularity w.r.t. closed supersets of a given nonempty $G \subseteq X$.

Comment: A fat cantor set has positive measure and no open subsets besides the empty set, so the Lebesgue measure does not have the desired property. On the other hand, any closed superset of the rational numbers contains their closure, which is all of $\mathbb{R}$, yet the rationals have measure zero, so the other property doesn't hold either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\Bbb R$ and $A=([0,1]\setminus \Bbb Q)$ we see that $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$ and $\lambda(A)=1$, so inner regularity wrt open sets is quite hopeless. Similarly $B=[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$ has $\lambda(B)=0$ while all closed sets that contain $B$ contain $[0,1]$ and so approaching from outside with closed sets we'll never go below $1$.